# Adding total of columns in datatable doesn't work

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, datatable, datatables

I'm using angular datatables and I wanted to add the sum or total of a column to the footer of the table just like below : [image]

I followed the footerCallback code just like the documentation but the difference is that I have ajax call and the datatable this.api() method is returning no values for columns and rows, any help please ?

```
this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 10,
      serverSide: true,
      processing: true,
      ordering: false,
      searchDelay: 1000,
      search: { return: true },
      footerCallback: function (row: any, data: any, start: any, end: any, display: any) {
        var api = this.api();

        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function (i:any) {
          return Number(i);
        };

        // Total over all pages
        let total = api
          .column(4)
          .data()
          .reduce(function (a: any, b: any) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
          }, 0);

        // Total over this page
        let pageTotal = api
          .column(4, { page: 'current' })
          .data()
          .reduce(function (a: any, b: any) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
          }, 0);

        // Update footer
        $(api.column(4).footer()).html('$' + pageTotal + ' ( $' + total + ' total)');
      },
      ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback: any) => {

        this.reportService.getReports(dataTablesParameters).subscribe({
            next: (result) => {
              this.array = result.data;
              this.spinner.hide();
            },
            error: (error) => {
              if (error?.status == 403) {
                this.toastr.error('Forbidden', 'Oops :(');
                this.spinner.hide();
                return;
              }
              var message = error.error.message;
              if (!message)
                message = "Unknown error occurred, Contact The System Administrator";

              this.toastr.error(message, 'Oops :(');
            }
          });
      },
    };`
```

I tried to console.log() a message with footerCallback and it works correctly and also tried to return "test" but nothing printed so I don't think I understand how to add html to a datatable.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a CSS class in the total column, let's say class "subtotal" and then inside the footerCallback function, you can use the row instead, i.e.

```
$(row).find("td.subtotal").html('$' + pageTotal + ' ( $' + total + ' total)');
```

Comment: the problem is this.api() is not returning values for rows or columns so I need a way to trigger the footerCallback after ajax call

Comment: @AMN wrote: "I followed the footerCallback code just like the documentation" What documentation, can you update your question adding the link of the documentation? Really I don't understand what dataTable are you using